# How is an IAsyncCursor used for iteration with the mongodb c# driver?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, async-await, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to get a list of all the databases in my server and ultimately print them out (i.e. use their names as `string`s). With the previous version of the c# driver I could call the `Server.GetDatabases()`, but that has been replaced with `ListDatabasesAsync()`.

The return value is an `IAsyncCursor<>` and I'm not sure what to do with it. How does one iterate through the list of databases (or anything) with such a cursor?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Use the built-in driver method (e.g. `ForEachAsync`, `ToListAsync`).
2. On C# 8.0 and above you can convert the `IAsyncCursor` into an `IAsyncEnumerable` and use `await foreach` or any async LINQ operator.
3. Iterate over the `IAsyncCursor`.

###### Built-in Driver Methods

The driver has some LINQ-like extension methods for `IAsyncCursor`, like `AnyAsync`, `ToListAsync`, etc. For iteration it has `ForEachAsync`:

```
var cursor = await client.ListDatabasesAsync();
await cursor.ForEachAsync(db => Console.WriteLine(db["name"]));
```

###### Converting to `IAsyncEnumerable`

On C# 8.0 and above it's much nicer to iterate with `await foreach` (and use async LINQ). This requires wrapping the `IAsyncCursor` in an `IAsyncEnumerable`.
You can do it yourself but since its important to get some critical things right (like cancellation and disposal) I've published a nuget package: [MongoAsyncEnumerableAdapter](https://github.com/i3arnon/MongoAsyncEnumerableAdapter)

```
var cursor = await client.ListDatabasesAsync();
await foreach (var db in cursor.ToAsyncEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine(db["name"]);
}
```

###### Custom iteration

Traditional iteration in C# is done with `IEnumerable` and `foreach`. `foreach` is the compiler's syntactic sugar. It's actually a call to `GetEnumerator`, a `using` scope and a `while` loop:

```
using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var current = enumerator.Current;
        // use current.
    }
}
```

`IAsyncCursor` is equivalent to `IEnumerator` (the result of `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`) while `IAsyncCursorSource` is to `IEnumerable`. The difference is that these support `async` (and get a batch each iteration and not just a single item). So you can implement the whole `using`, `while` loop thing yourself:

```
IAsyncCursorSource<int> cursorSource = null;

using (var asyncCursor = await cursorSource.ToCursorAsync())
{
    while (await asyncCursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        foreach (var current in asyncCursor.Current)
        {
            // use current
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it save to modiy the document in `ForEachAsync` and save it back to db using `ReplaceOneAsync`? Modifications in this case are to complex to use `UpdateManyAsync`

Comment: @hansmaad yes. It is safe. Just less efficient.

Answer (score 13):

I personally like to convert the cursor into a C# 8 `IAsyncEnumerable`, that way you get all the benefits of working with enumerables (`LINQ` mainly).

Using @i3arnon's "long answer" I created this extension method:

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ToAsyncEnumerable<T>(this IAsyncCursor<T> asyncCursor)
{
    while (await asyncCursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        foreach (var current in asyncCursor.Current)
        {
            yield return current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This implementation misses some key points like cancellation and disposable (which may lead to leaks and deadlocks). I made a nuget package with a simple adapter you can use: https://github.com/i3arnon/MongoAsyncEnumerableAdapter

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the support of extension methods for `GetAsyncEnumerator` in C# 9 and the duck-typed implementation of `foreach` it is now possible to iterate the cursor directly using the following extension method:

```
public static class MongoDbCursorExtensions
{
    public static IAsyncCursor<T> GetAsyncEnumerator<T>(this IAsyncCursor<T> cursor) => cursor;
}
```

Usage:

```
var cursor = await collection.Find(filter).ToCursorAsync();
await foreach (var batch in cursor) // extension method implicitly called here
{
    foreach (var item in batch)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement