# In C#, how can I extract a block of code which yields the return?

Tags: c#, iterator, task, refactoring, iasyncenumerable

I have several methods which all end:

```
while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
{
    foreach (FieldServiceAppointment appointment in cursor.Current)
    {
        yield return appointment;
    }
}
```

For example:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<FieldServiceAppointment> GetEventWithWorkOrderType(
    string workOrderType, string customerId)
{
    using IAsyncCursor<FieldServiceAppointment> cursor = await FieldServiceAppointments.FindAsync(
        x => x.BusinessEventTypeCode == workOrderType
            && x.CustomerCode == customerId
        );

    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        foreach (FieldServiceAppointment appointment in cursor.Current)
        {
            yield return appointment;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to remove this duplication.

If I try to refactor it to this:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<FieldServiceAppointment> GetEventWithWorkOrderType(
    string workOrderType, string customerId)
{
    using IAsyncCursor<FieldServiceAppointment> cursor = await FieldServiceAppointments.FindAsync(
        x => x.BusinessEventTypeCode == workOrderType
            && x.CustomerCode == customerId
        );
    YieldAppointments(cursor);
}

public async IAsyncEnumerable<FieldServiceAppointment> YieldAppointments(
    IAsyncCursor<FieldServiceAppointment> cursor)
{
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        foreach (FieldServiceAppointment appointment in cursor.Current)
        {
            yield return appointment;
        }
    }
}
```

It won't compile because I can't return a value from an iterator.

If I try to return  `yield return YieldAppointments(cursor);`, it won't compile because:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<DataAccessLayer.Entities.Praxedo.FieldServiceAppointment>'
> to 'DataAccessLayer.Entities.Praxedo.FieldServiceAppointment'. An
> explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
> cast?)    DataAccessLayer C:\projects\EnpalPraxedoIntegration\DataAccessLayer\DbServices\FieldServiceAutomationDbService.cs   78  Active

So I tried to

`yield return (IAsyncEnumerable<FieldServiceAppointment>) YieldAppointments(cursor);`

and

`yield return YieldAppointments(cursor) as IAsyncEnumerable <FieldServiceAppointment>;`

either of which generate a compiler error of:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<DataAccessLayer.Entities.Praxedo.FieldServiceAppointment>'
> to 'DataAccessLayer.Entities.Praxedo.FieldServiceAppointment'. An
> explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
> cast?)    DataAccessLayer C:\projects\EnpalPraxedoIntegration\DataAccessLayer\DbServices\FieldServiceAutomationDbService.cs   78  Active

So then I tried:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<FieldServiceAppointment> GetEventWithWorkOrderType(
    string workOrderType, string customerId)
{
    using IAsyncCursor<FieldServiceAppointment> cursor = await FieldServiceAppointments.FindAsync(
        x => x.BusinessEventTypeCode == workOrderType
            && x.CustomerCode == customerId
        );
    yield return await YieldAppointments(cursor);
}

public async Task<FieldServiceAppointment> YieldAppointments(
    IAsyncCursor<FieldServiceAppointment> cursor)
{
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        foreach (FieldServiceAppointment appointment in cursor.Current)
        {
            yield return appointment;
        }
    }
}
```

but this won't compile because

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1624  The body of
> 'FieldServiceAutomationDbService.YieldAppointments(IAsyncCursor)'
> cannot be an iterator block because 'Task' is
> not an iterator interface
> type  DataAccessLayer C:\projects\EnpalPraxedoIntegration\DataAccessLayer\DbServices\FieldServiceAutomationDbService.cs   81  Active

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: `return YieldAppointments(cursor);`?

Comment: @Llama Nope https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917317/why-am-i-not-allowed-to-return-an-iasyncenumerable-in-a-method-returning-an-iasy

Comment: So the problem is mixing `async` / `await`. Shift the await into YieldAppointments so that `GetEventWithWorkOrderType` isn't `async`?`YieldAppointments(Task<IAsyncCursor<FieldServiceAppointment>> cursor)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to use the [`AsyncEnumerableEx.Using`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Using.cs) method from the [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/) package, and the `ToAsyncEnumerable` extension method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682371/how-is-an-iasynccursor-used-for-iteration-with-the-mongodb-c-sharp-driver/62492816#62492816) by Tom Gringauz.

Below is the signature of the `AsyncEnumerableEx.Using` method:

```
public static IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> Using<TSource, TResource>(
    Func<Task<TResource>> resourceFactory,
    Func<TResource, ValueTask<IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>>> enumerableFactory)
    where TResource : IDisposable;
```

Below is the `ToAsyncEnumerable` extension method, copy-pasted from the aforementioned answer, enhanced with cancellation support:

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ToAsyncEnumerable<T>(
    this IAsyncCursor<T> asyncCursor,
    [EnumeratorCancellation]CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    while (await asyncCursor.MoveNextAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        foreach (var current in asyncCursor.Current)
            yield return current;
}
```

Here is how to combine these two methods, in order to solve your problem:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<FieldServiceAppointment> GetEventWithWorkOrderType(
    string workOrderType, string customerId)
{
    return AsyncEnumerableEx.Using(() => FieldServiceAppointments
        .FindAsync(x => x.BusinessEventTypeCode == workOrderType &&
            x.CustomerCode == customerId),
        cursor => new ValueTask<IAsyncEnumerable<FieldServiceAppointment>>(cursor.ToAsyncEnumerable()));
}
```

The `AsyncEnumerableEx.Using` has an overly flexible `enumerableFactory` parameter, that (in your case) requires wrapping the `cursor.ToAsyncEnumerable()` invocation in a verbose and noisy `ValueTask`. You could get rid of this annoyance by wrapping the `AsyncEnumerableEx.Using` in your own `Using` method:

```
public static IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> Using<TSource, TResource>(
    Func<Task<TResource>> resourceFactory,
    Func<TResource, IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>> enumerableFactory)
    where TResource : IDisposable
{
    return AsyncEnumerableEx.Using(resourceFactory,
        resource => new ValueTask<IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>>(
            enumerableFactory(resource)));
}
```

With this method the solution becomes simpler and more readable:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<FieldServiceAppointment> GetEventWithWorkOrderType(
    string workOrderType, string customerId)
{
    return Using(() => FieldServiceAppointments
        .FindAsync(x => x.BusinessEventTypeCode == workOrderType &&
            x.CustomerCode == customerId),
        cursor => cursor.ToAsyncEnumerable());
}
```

---

**Alternative:** Below is a self-sufficient and less abstract alternative. The `FromAsyncCursor` generic method takes an `asyncCursorFactory`, and returns a sequence that contains the documents emitted by the cursor:

```
public async static IAsyncEnumerable<TDocument> FromAsyncCursor<TDocument>(
    Func<Task<IAsyncCursor<TDocument>>> asyncCursorFactory,
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    using var asyncCursor = await asyncCursorFactory();
    while (await asyncCursor.MoveNextAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        foreach (var current in asyncCursor.Current)
            yield return current;
}
```

Usage example:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<FieldServiceAppointment> GetEventWithWorkOrderType(
    string workOrderType, string customerId)
{
    return FromAsyncCursor(() => FieldServiceAppointments.FindAsync(
        x => x.BusinessEventTypeCode == workOrderType && x.CustomerCode == customerId));
}
```

The [`EnumeratorCancellation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.enumeratorcancellationattribute) attribute makes it possible to consume the generated sequence, while observing a `CancellationToken`:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
await foreach (var item in GetEventWithWorkOrderType("xxx", "yyy")
    .WithCancellation(cts.Token))
{
    //...
}
```

Although the `GetEventWithWorkOrderType` method does not accept a `CancellationToken` itself, the token is magically propagated to the `FromAsyncCursor` method, because of this attribute. All this is probably a bit academic though, because it's unlikely that a single `MoveNextAsync` will take so much time to fetch the next batch of documents, to make adding cancellation support a compelling proposition.

Comment: This doesn't compile, but rather results in Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursor<DataAccessLayer.Entities.Praxedo.FieldServiceAppointment>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<DataAccessLayer.Entities.Praxedo.FieldServiceAppointment>>' DataAccessLayer C:\projects\EnpalPraxedoIntegration\DataAccessLayer\DbServices\FieldServiceAutomationDbService.cs 72 Active

Comment: @BrianKessler hmm, see [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YLIM8D) fiddle. I made some assumptions about the API that you are using. My example compiles under these assumptions.

Comment: cheers for the response.  I'm afraid I'm a bit too much of a C# newbie to figure out how to confirm your assumptions or supply the policy.   ... but I think I figured out the problem.... I was trying to put all the relevant code into the class where I would use it, where most methods should be instance methods.  But the extension method can't be an instance method or live in a non-static class...

Comment: @BrianKessler yeap, extension methods are only allowed in static classes. Btw using the tools made by the [Rx team](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/rxteam), can make anyone feel like a newbie. They are quite intimidating!

Comment: @BrianKessler FYI I added an alternative solution in the answer.

Comment: Awesome!  I like this answer better, not only for being self-sufficient, but I think it is even more readable.  :-)

Comment: @BrianKessler to be fair the `FromAsyncCursor` method is just a generalized version of the `YieldAppointments` method in [Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69659993/in-c-how-can-i-extract-a-block-of-code-which-yields-the-return/69660348#69660348). :-)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that.  I was originally tempted to accept his answer instead, but I found your answer more informative and more reusable.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about parameterising `YieldAppointments` with a `Task` that gives you a cursor?

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<FieldServiceAppointment> YieldAppointments(Func<Task<IAsyncCursor<FieldServiceAppointment>>> cursorTask)
{
    using var cursor = await cursorTask();
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        foreach (FieldServiceAppointment appointment in cursor.Current)
        {
            yield return appointment;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can write the first part of `GetEventWithWorkOrderType` (where you get the cursor, plus whatever other async operations that you might do) inside a lambda:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<FieldServiceAppointment> GetEventWithWorkOrderType(string workOrderType, string customerId)
    => YieldAppointments(async () =>
        await FieldServiceAppointments.FindAsync(
            x => x.BusinessEventTypeCode == workOrderType
                && x.CustomerCode == customerId
        );
    );
```